# Линия от href на картинке

Tags: html

Хотел сделать картинку-ссылку, но после картинки появляется такая маленькая штучка типа "_" как подчеркивание. Откуда она могла взяться?

```
<a href="#" ><img src="img/menu1.gif" width="130" height="40"/></a>
```

Comment: а здесь: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6ZyXj/ обводит в ie или других браузерах ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так уберите подчеркивание, если оно не нужно. Вот пример через [css](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000074.htm).

Comment: опа не подумал)спасибо)

Comment: у меня появились еще проблемы...зашел на сайт с IE он обводит ссылку text-decoration не помогает что делать?

Comment: Добавьте:

    a img{
        border: none;
    }

Comment: попробуй так, img { border : 0 ;}

Comment: @Deonis спасибо...помогло)